# ngx tabs (V2.0.0) remove icon (X) shows in red color in phones / devices

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

tabs with remove icon(X) shows as white in desktop , when I opened the same view in phone /ipad icon(X) shows in red

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change using FontAwesome icon.

```
:host /deep/ .nav-link .bs-remove-tab {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0em;
}

:host /deep/ .nav-link .bs-remove-tab::after {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    /*--adjust as necessary--*/
    color: #F44336;
    font-size: 13px;
    // padding-right: 0.3em;
    left: 0.3em;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the css component:

```
:host /deep/ .nav-link .bs-remove-tab {
    background: blueviolet !important;
}
```